# How can the thermal conductivity of a binary gas mixture be estimated?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, heat, reference-request

Recently, I am seeking for a simple but relatively accurate method to estimate the thermal conductivity of a binary gas mixture, say ethanol vapor + nitrogen. I assume the mixture as ideal gas.

The molar fraction and thermal conductivities of the components are known. The parameters for a try are: mole fraction of ethanol vapor: $x_A=0.2$, thermal conductivity of ethanol vapor and nitrogen are $k_A=0.016\ \mathrm{W/(m\,K)}$, $k_B=0.026\ \mathrm{W/(m\,K)}$, temperature of the mixture gas $T=330\ \mathrm{K}$, and the bulk pressure is $101\ \mathrm{kPa}$.

I really hope someone could give me a hint or point me to a classical reference.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking you could use the Fourier equation for heat flux

$$
\phi =K \frac{S\theta}{e} \,\, ,
$$
where

- $\phi$ = Heat flux
- $K$ = Termal conductivity coeficient in units of  $kcal  s^{-1}\ m^{-2}\ K^{-1} /m^{-1}$
- $S$ = Area of the section you're dealing $m^{2}$
- $θ$ = Difference of temperature $K$
- $e$ = Thickness in $m$.

And use for the resulting thermal conductivity the fraction

$$
K_{r}=\frac{\sum K_{i}J_{i}(M_{i})^{1/3}}{\sum J_{i}(M_{i})^{1/3}} \,\, ,
$$
where:

- $K_{r}$ = Resulting termal conductivity of the moisture;
- $K_{i}$ = Termal conductivity of each gas;
- $j_{i}$ = Molar fraction of each gas;
- $M_{i}$ = molar mass of each gas.

I think it'll work with some 2% of standard deviation. If you're able to read in portuguese, here is the link of my reference:

[Reference](http://www.mecatronicaatual.com.br/educacao/1092-analisadores-por-condutibilidade-trmica?showall=&limitstart=)

And here is the link of the [Book](http://dl.afterburner.ir/Bird%20R.B.,%20Stewart%20W.E.,%20Lightfoot%20E.N.%20Transport%20phenomena%28www.mehr.ir%29.pdf) cited by @Chester Miller.

I hope I hope I was Helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

See also Section 9.3 Theory of Thermal Conductivity of Gases at Low Density in Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.

Comment: Hi @ Chester Miller, thank for your answer, but I can not find this reference in the library database... Could you please share me your soft copy? Many thank!

Comment: I don't understand.  This is a very well known book.  It has been in use for over 50 years, and has stood the test of time.  A new edition came out in around 2000.  Here is the reference again:  Bird, R.B., Stewart, W.E., and Lightfoot, E. N., Transport Phenomena, John Wiley, New York, 2nd Edition, 2002.

Comment: Unfortunately I may have to disagree that this answers the question. Could you include some of the relevant parts of the book here?

Comment: Isn't mentioning Section 9.3 good enough?  I'm uncomfortable with the IP implications of copying some of the text.  If you want, I can try to paraphrase some of it.

Comment: @ChesterMiller, I think I have misunderstood your citation. The title of the book is  **Transport Phenomena**, which is indeed a wonderful book!

Comment: In my long career as a ChE in industry, I used Transport Phenomena much more than all my other books combined.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/48361)

Comment: @Jan Thank you for your "timely" response.  It's only a year late.

Comment: OP asked for a reference, so in my opinion, your answer is fine, albeit rather brief. It might be better if you could include some of the information from there, but that's up to you. (It's not NAA.)

Comment: @ChesterMiller Some things only turn up if they are flagged. I saw the flag in the Low Quality Posts review queue and responded accordingly. I wouldn’t have opened the post in itself since I don’t know much about the topic, but imho this is not an answer, just a reference point. Four other reviewers agree with me.